# Why it throws null pointer exception when object is initialized to null and then trying to access class method?

Tags: java

```
public class Abc
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      def obj=null;
      obj.method();
    }
}
class Def
{
   void method()
   {
       System.out.println("class def->>> method()");
   }
}
```

The output of this code is generating a NullPointerException and why?

Comment: please read the javadoc for `NullPointerException`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` means you tried to deference a `null` value so you get the expected behaviour.

It doesn't have anything to do with detecting uninitialised values. It's not called `UninitialisedException`